# Log4j not working

Tags: log4j

I using common logging and jboss eap 6.2 in java application, log file is creating but empty and hibernate log also not working.

This is my jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="abc.war">
         <exclusions>
             <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
             <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
         </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

and this is my log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=c\:\\log\\eSocietySQLLog.log
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c %n%m%C
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd-a
```

and add JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false" in standalone.conf of jboss eap 6.2.

Comment: Error ?. Share your conf file too the line of JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the answer, my log4j is working.

1) I create the module in my jboss eap 6.2 GA `jboss_home/modules/com`

1. module is `log4j/mylog4j/main`
2. in main folder putted the `module.xml` file and `log4j-1.2.16.jar`

#### module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.fourthdti.esociety">  
    <resources>  
        <resource-root path="log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>  
    </resources>  
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>  
        <module name="javax.api"/>
    </dependencies>  
</module>
```

2) Add the single line code at end file `standalone.conf` which is in `JBOSS_HOME/bin`

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false"
```

3) Create the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in my `META_INF` of ear

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment name="eSociety-ear.ear">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.log4j.mylog4j" export="true" />
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.antlr"/>
            <module name="org.hibernate.*"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="abc-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.antlr"/>
            <module name="org.hibernate.*"/>
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="abc-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.antlr"/>
            <module name="org.hibernate.*"/>
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

4) Putted `log4j.properties` in my class path

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE, stdout

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=debug
log4j.logger.org.springframework=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=trace
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type= trace
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=warn
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=trace

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=c\:\\log\\eSociety.log
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=2
```

5) Add dependencies in `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
             <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
             <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

It is enough for my log4j configuration.

Comment: What is the significance (necessity) of the dependency on "javax.api" and was it necessary to exclude everything you excluded?

Comment: It seems overly complicated.